# Expected declaration when adding values to a Swift dictionary

Tags: swift

I get the error "**expected declaration**" on the last line when trying to add values to the dictionary tablesBooked.

```
class BookingSystem {

    var tablesBooked = Dictionary<Int, String>()
    var table = Table(tableID: 1 , tableCapacity: 2, status: "A")
    var bookings = [Booking]()

    tablesBooked.setValue(table.status, forKey: table.tableID)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because your line setValue **cannot just live here inside your class without being inside a method**. Of course here it really depends on what (and how) you want to accomplish, but you could put it in the `init()` method of your `BookingSystem` class, or you could build your own custom `init()`.

Here is how it would look like:

```
    import Foundation

    class Booking {

        // Some interesting things here

    }

    class Table : NSObject {

        // MARK: Properties

        var tableID: Int
        var tableCapacity: Int
        var status: String

        // MARK: Initializers

        init(tableID: Int, tableCapacity: Int, status: String) {
            self.tableID = tableID
            self.tableCapacity = tableCapacity
            self.status = status
        }

    }


    class BookingSystem {

        // MARK: Properties

        var tablesBooked = [Int: String]()

        var table = Table(tableID: 1 , tableCapacity: 2, status: "A")

        var bookings = [Booking]()

        // MARK: Initializers

        init() {

            // I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but anyway you should add it in a custom method or your init. If I were to use the code in your example, you would add this here:

            tablesBooked[table.tableID] = table.status
        }

        // ...
    }
```

I added the `Table` class here on purpose, just to show you an example on how to create your own custom init.

Also, **another thing worth mentioning here** is that `Swift Dictionaries` don't have a `setValue:forKey:` method. Instead, to add an object to your `Dictionary`, you should use:

```
yourDictionnary["yourKey"] = yourValue
```

Hope it helps, and if you have any questions just feel free asking :)

Comment: Why did you make `Table` extend `NSObject`?

Comment: That's just an example here even though it's not really related to the question. But indeed if the content of this class was limited to what I wrote, then you wouldn't obviously need to extend NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

Use init method:

```
class BookingSystem {

     var tablesBooked = Dictionary<Int, String>()
     var table = Table(tableID: 1 , tableCapacity: 2, status: "A")
     var bookings = [Booking]()

     init() {
          tablesBooked.setValue(table.status, forKey: table.tableID)
     }
}
```

Comment: Why use `setValue(_:forKey:)` ?